# use of undeclared type 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate swift'

Tags: ios, swift, sms

i am trying to implement sending a text message using the MFMessageComposeViewController object. But when i am trying to declare the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol. In ViewController.swift i get the following error : **use of undeclared type 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate swift'**

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
    messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `MFMessageComposeViewController` doesn't give an issue? Did you import `MessageUI` (its framework) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `MessageUI` Framework,

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

}
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to add

```
import MessageUI
```

at the top of your swift file. Also, you better to add check

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
```

before send message, and don't forget to dismiss your message controller in delegate method

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need delegate to implement

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
        switch result.rawValue {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
            print("message cancelled")

        case MessageComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
            print("message failed")

        case MessageComposeResultSent.rawValue:
            print("message sent")

        default:
            break
        }

        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Think it's helpful!